Problem sending Persian emails with django's EmailMessage
I'm fairly new to django and was trying to send an email containing Persian letters using django.core.mail.EmailMessage . here is my code:
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings


def custom_sender(subject: str, body: str, recipient_list: list[str], attachments: list[str] = (), content_type_html: bool = False):
    try:
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject,
            body,
            settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            recipient_list,
        )

        if content_type_html:
            email.content_subtype = "html"

        for attachment in attachments:
            email.attach_file(attachment)

        email.send()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'\n\nFailed to send email: {e}\n\n')

and this is how I tried to use it in my view :
custom_sender(subject='ایمیل تستی',
              body='این یک ایمیل تستی است.',
              recipient_list=[user.email])


but I encounter this error :
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
I have noticed that I can't even print Persian stuff out in the console in my django project and I keep encountering this same error (this doesn't happen outside of my django project, and I CAN print Persian letters out in the console). can someone please tell me what this error is about and how I can fix it?
I asked some AIs and tried a bunch of solutions like encoding the subject and body using .encode('utf-8') and using django's smart_str , or using python's unicode strings like
u'این یک پیام تستی است'
I even tried messing around with django's settings.py like trying to change the DEFAULT_CHARSET (although it already is set to 'utf-8'  by default) or changing the default language to Persian to see if it helps, but none of those work and the error remains.
BTW I'm using a windows 10 machine, python 3.12 and django 5.0

I´ve just created an EmailMessage object with your text - and it does encode the header according to RFC 2231 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2231.html) using utf-8 (which won´t yield any encoding errors). I suppose you are using Windows? That is the only Python environment where all encodings don´t default to utf-8, instead using system encoding (that would also explain why you can´t print to the terminal)

@jsbueno  thanks. how can I fix this problem? (besides not using windows anymore)
and if this issue is not related to django , why is it that I can print Persian stuff in my console outside of this specific django project?

Did you sen "local middleware" into your settings.py?

@Mehdi Where would I put that? can you give me the exact line or lines of code that I need to put in my settings.py ?

You can get rid of charmap issues (which are a Windows-only thing, and a console-only thing) by using the Python UTF-8 Mode.

First, You need to config your time zone in settings.py :
import locale

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa-ir'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fa_IR.UTF-8")

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

and than config your middleware in settings.py like this :
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

Pay attention : Local middleware must take place after the Common middleware.
for more information see this post.
Make these changes to your project and send further information. Good luck.

because if you TAKE A LOOK AT WHAT I TYPED, PROBABLY YOU CAN SEE THIS LINE : locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fa_IR.UTF-8"). OK? When you wanna use aother type of encoding, You should mention it. That's why I changed timezone and language.

He has plan to use "Persian" words not just ASCII characters.

As far as I can tell, locale.setlocale() won't affect the Windows console encoding, which is where charmap-related issues come from. And yes, I understand OP is trying to use non-ASCII characters; I'm familiar with that, since I work with Finnish text a lot. :)

In my machine worked just fine.

What worked just fine? Sending emails, or printing Persian text onto a Windows console that has a non-UTF8 codepage (because the latter is what OP is actually having problems with)?

If you're using PowerShell, AFAIK it's already UTF-8 native. They might not be. But Python UTF-8 Mode (as I linked in a comment for OP's post) should fix that anyway.

I think, he use CMD not PowerShell, looks like some CMD fonts have issue with Persian words.

The fonts used by a traditional Windows console are one thing, but the more pressing issue is the console codepage – if the console codepage does not support the characters that Python is trying to print, you get a charmap-related encoding error. This is fixed by UTF-8 Mode. But timezones, setlocale or the locale middleware have nothing to do with that.
